# How can I use jQuery animation to animate a block changing color?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I would like to get this animation using jQuery:

[image: Here is [a link](http://oi57.tinypic.com/hueeeu.jpg) to the animation.]

I have tried the following and it is not working:

```
<script>
    $(function () {
        $("#b").click(function () {
            $("r").animate({
                width: 50}, 2000)
        });
    });
</script>
<div id="b"><div id="r"></div></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do a few things here, like add height also. You also need to ensure you have the CSS setup correctly to begin with

DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/363vE/

```
$("#b").click(function(){                    
        $("#r").animate({
            height:200,
            width: 200
        }, "medium");
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

It's `$("#r")`, not `$("r")`. You're selecting the ID, like `$("#b")`

Comment: i didn't saw my mistake